# How do I change the PCI device ID of my graphics card in the system? (to install Quadro driver on a GeForce)

Tags: nvidia, pci

I have a consumer GeForce GTX680. It's professional equivalent is Quadro K5000. Both cards have exactly the same chip inside (GK104), the hardware is nearly identical.

The official driver for GTX680 can't do Quad-buffered stereo, but the one for K5000 can. One can unlock these "professional" features on the GTX680 by installing the K5000 driver on it. [It has been successfully done on Windows.](https://web.archive.org/web/20101002091227/http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=539&pgno=3)

**How do I change the PCI device ID of the card in my system, so the installer thinks it's K5000, not GTX680?**

I need to change the value of register 02 from 1180 to 11BA.

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] (rev a1)
```

Tells me the graphics card is on "01:00.0"

```
setpci --dumpregs
    cap pos w name
         00 W VENDOR_ID
         02 W DEVICE_ID
```

Tells me 02 corresponds to device ID. To read the register I do:

```
sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 02.w
    1180
```

"1180" Means "GTX680", I need to change it to "11BA" which means "K5000"

so I'm changing 1180 to 11BA:

```
sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 02.w=11BA
```

**Goes through with no errors but when I try to read the value I just changed it's still showing 1180**

```
sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 02.w
1180
```

Also tried the same thing as sudo su (as sometimes sudo doesn't work)

```
[aaa@bbb ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for aaa: 
[root@bbb aaa]# setpci -v -s 01:00.0 DEVICE_ID=11BA
0000:01:00.0 @02 11ba
[root@bbb aaa]# setpci -v -s 01:00.0 DEVICE_ID
0000:01:00.0 @02 = 1180
```

I understand this memory can't be really written into so this might be just something being done in the system and therefore not showing. I tried installing the Quadro driver and it's still installs the one for GTX680 (no quad-buffering features)

I managed to change the device ID of the card by changing resistors on it but it still didn't allow changing the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to look through the driver itself. If no source code is available, you may have luck patching with a hex editor

If the driver is signed in any way,however, this will invalidate the signature.

You might also be able to create a fake device and bind the real one to the stub driver, using the fake device to relay. Can't say how easy that'll be for sure,but it'll require decent kernel level skills. You'd have to implement a virtual pci device in the kernel itself.

Option three is really heavy: create a VM, modify it to report the desired PCI ID and bind the device to the VM. But this limits your usability and incurs the performance penalty of a virtual machine.

Comment: We could really use a software tool for this and I think it should be part of the system by default like for example Wii remote support. The number of crippled Nvidia GFX cards that could be unlocked...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `setpci` command for that: http://linux.die.net/man/8/setpci

With setpci --dumpregs you can find out about the general hardware registers and then use setpci to query the device address (02:00.0) with, for example, one of these registers:

```
setpci -s 02:00.0 STATUS
```

Comment: When I change the value of my DEVICE_ID the command goes through without errors, but when I read the register I just changed - I see no change.

Comment: I also tried 'sudo su
echo "10DE 11BA" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/new_id' and it didn't work.